# clear a file input that is in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of file inputs being generated from an array with ng-repeat. I would like to be able to clear the input after the upload has been completed. So for example the uploaded file was at index 1 of the array. I would not that the upload is complete I would like the file input associated with that index (1) to be cleared. I tried binding to ng-model at first but that didn't work. Should I use $broadcast?? There a way to find the the value of the input?

```js
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, $q, FileFactory){
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.ff = FileFactory;
    
    $scope.upload = function(){
        
        var defer = $q.defer();
        
        defer.promise(function(data){
            
            
        })

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", FileFactory.uploads[$scope.index].file);
        formData.append("file", FileFactory.uploads[$scope.index].fileName);

        http.open("POST", "upload.cfc?method=upload");

        http.addEventListener("load", function(){

            if(this.status = 200){

                // code to clear the input?

            }

        })

        http.send(formData);
        
    }

})

.factory('FileFactory', function(){

    var uploads = [
        { file:null, fileName:null, },
        { file:null, fileName:null, },
        { file:null, fileName:null, }
    ];

    return uploads;

})

.directive('fileUpload', function(FileFactory){

    return {
        scope:{
            fileUpload:"=",
            index:"@"
        },
        restrict:"A",
        link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){

            element.bind('change', function(e){

                FileFactory.uploads[scope.index].file = e.target.files[0];
                FileFactory.uploas[scope.index].fileName = e.target.files[0].name;

            })

        }
    }

})


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('html'), ['app']);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <div class="repeat" ng-repeat="item in app.ff track by $index">
        <input type="file" file-upload index="{{$index}}">
        <input type="button" ng-click="upload($index)" value="upload">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your upload function, you should get the index that you are passing in the html like so:

```
$scope.upload = function(index){

   ...

   formData.append("file", FileFactory.uploads[index].file);
   formData.append("file", FileFactory.uploads[index].fileName);

}
```

Comment: I was trying to clear it without querying the DOM but it seems like that's the only way to do it. I was trying to get a reference to the variable that is being created by the binding and make that an empty string.